# Laravel view error on getting data from two different tables

Tags: html, laravel

### HTML view  blade for data gathered from database

could not get the data from another table I don't know why

```
@if(count($shift))
    @foreach($shift as $data)
    <tr>
    <td>{{$data->serial}}</td>
        <td>{{$data->date}}</td>
        <td>{{$data->startshift}}</td>
        <td>{{$data->endshift}}</td>
    @foreach($tracking as $track)
      <!--here is the problem-->
    @endforeach 
    @endforeach 
    </tr>
```

### controller  to connect database and views

```
    $shift = DB::table('employee_schedule')
  ->select('id','user_id as user_id','serial as serial','date as date','startshift as startshift','endshift as endshift')
  ->orderBy('id','ASC')
  ->paginate(5);

$tracking = DB::table('empsheduling')
->select('serial as serial','date as date','startshift as startshift','endshift as endshift','Hourswork as Hourswork')
->first();
                            
return view('shifTracker.viewshifTracker',compact('shift','tracking'));
```

Comment: what's the problem? what is your expected and actual output?

Comment: Why don't you use models? Is there any particular reason?

Comment: i really don't know how to create model can you help me with it

Comment: @ZeroValue Serve yourself with the documentation at https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have selected the first record of empsheduling table, look at the end of your query: `first()`.

Either replace `first()` with `get()` or in your view remove loop and get the data with `$tracking->data`.

Answer (score 0):

I already did find the solution by changing first() to get(). Thanks